# How to pass a collection of <Model> from view to Controller in .net mvc

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, arraylist, web-development-server

thanks for taking the time to read my question.... 
The solution doesn't have to be with ajax ... i need anything to make this work as described....

I need to do the following 
[Image for the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMa1Q.jpg)
if i select **private cars** from the ad type it shows only the private cars, if i select **BMW** Make it shows only BMW , and so on for the rest of the search... i did that ..

The problem is when i try to combine multiple searches parameters

example: if i need to show only the **private Used cars** which are **BMW** and in specific city and sort the result by price or mileage etc....

I didn't manage to do that ... i tried to wrap the results every time as a list then pass this list by ajax to a controller to do the stuff then retrieve it in a partial View... but i couldn't pass This list (list(Class UserCar))......
I think that if a generous man guided me to do sorting right , it will be same for all search parameters...

This is the view model which contains usercar Model which have all the data i want to retrieve from database

```
public class VMUserCar
{
    public UserCar UserCar { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserCar> CarsList { get; set; }
    public int? CarsListCount{ get { return CarsList.Count(); } }
}
```

This is the Index which contains the partial View

```
<div class="searchDiv">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial_Views/_DisplayAds/_SearchResultDisplay.cshtml")
 </div>
```

This is the partial view which displays all the userCars which displayed in the site image above ( I removed html as possible to minimize distractions)

```
@model CarSales.Models.CarsForSale.VMUserCar

@foreach (var item in Model.CarsList)
{
 @item.Year  @item.Make  @item.Model @item.Badge @item.BodyStyle 
 @item.DriveType   --&& Other stuff--
}
```

```js
   @*SortBy (in the same view)*@
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var SortDD = $('#SortDD');
        var searchDiv = $('.searchDiv');
       
        var carsList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CarsList))';
        //var carsList1 = JSON.stringify(carsList);
        console.log("List: " + carsList);

      SortDD.change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                //processData: false,
                traditional: true,
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { list: carsList,searchValue: SortDD.val() },
                url: '@Url.Action("SortSearch", "DisplayAds")',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response) {
                    searchDiv.empty();
                    if (response !== null) {
                        searchDiv.append(response);
                    } else {
                        searchDiv.append("Search returns null from sort DD");
                    }
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert("Error from sort DD:  ", ex.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
     </script>
```

And this is the controller which will receive the ajax

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult SortSearch(string searchValue, IEnumerable<UserCar> list)
    {

        ViewBag.SortDD = new SelectList(Utilties.GetSortDD(), "Value", "Text", searchValue);

        switch (searchValue)
        {
            case "1":
                list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.AdCreationDate).ToList();
                break;

            case "2":
          list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Odometer).ToList();
                break;

            case "3":
               list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Make).ToList();
                break;
          --& other 10 cases--

   var vmUserCar = new VMUserCar() { CarsList = list};

        return PartialView("~/Views/Partial_Views/_DisplayAds/_SearchResultDisplay.cshtml",  vmUserCar );
    } --this is the same partial view which displays all the userCars --
```

When i run and ajax contains :
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
It gives me "Invalid JSON primitive: list1." and doesn't continue to action...

& when i run without it,  it goes to action but The list value on the controller is always null..
I tried '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CarsList))' alone and value is null always but when i console.log it.... i get json values..

and JSON.stringify(carsList) also null but no values at all when i console log it...

When i changed the list value of controller to IEnumerable list
It retrieves the values as one long string line but i don't know how to convert it to UserCar class

Thanks again for taking the time to read all of that... any help will be much appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(document).ready(function () { 
       function PassThings()
       {              
           var things = [
               { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
               { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
               { id: 3, color: 'red' }
           ];

           things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });

           $.ajax({
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'POST',
               url: $("body").attr("data-project-root") + "Administration/Actions/PassThings",
               data: things,
               success: function () {
                   $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
               },
               failure: function (response) {
                   $('#result').html(response);
               }
           }); 
       }
       PassThings();
   });
```

For this Controller ::

```
   public void PassThings(List<Thing> things)
    {
        var t = things;
    }
```

For this ViewModel ::

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Its must be work, and I recheck this.Would you please recheck this.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I tried that... and after : JSON.stringify({ 'things': things }); it gives me correct json ..... but in the controller's value  it's always null,       and if i made the class value to <dynamic> it accepts the json but it shows long string line... don't know how to use that...

Comment: Rechecked it again ... yes the same Error when using:      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',   In ajax it gives ( Invalid JSON primitive: list.) and when i remove the content type .. it passes the json with the correct data  but only when i make the receiver List<dynamic > other type it gives me null...

Comment: Although i checked the json with json validattor    https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/     and tells me valid json ... i still get the error invalid json primitive....